# Conventions for pmf/pdf

Tags: probability, density-function

The way I usually see the conventions:
for a continuous random variable $X$, the  pdf is denoted $f_{X}(x)$ or $f(x)$,where $x$ is an instance of $X$.

And for a discrete random variable $X$, the pmf  is written as  $P(X=x)$ or  $p(X=x)$ or $p_{X}(x)$ or $p(x)$ ,where $x$ is an instance of $X$.

I was looking at the convention in this paper and got a little confused:
https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume11/vincent10a/vincent10a.pdf

"
We will be using the following notation throughout the article:

- Random variables are written in upper case, for example, $X$.
- If $X$ is a random vector, then its $j^{\text {th }}$ component will be noted $X_{j}$.
- Ordinary vectors are written in lowercase bold. For example, a realization of a random vector $X$ may be written $\mathbf{x}$. Vectors are considered column vectors.
- Matrices are written in uppercase bold (e.g., W). I denotes the identity matrix.
- We use lower case $p$ and $q$ to denote both probability density functions or probability mass functions according to context.
- Let $X$ and $Y$ two random variables with marginal probability $p(X)$ and $p(Y)$. Their joint probability is written $p(X, Y)$ and the conditional $p(X \mid Y)$.
- We may use the following common shorthands when unambiguous: $p(\mathbf{x})$ for $p(X=\mathbf{x})$; $p(X \mid \mathbf{y})$ for $p(X \mid Y=\mathbf{y})$ (denoting a conditional distribution) and $p(\mathbf{x} \mid \mathbf{y})$ for $p(X=\mathbf{x} \mid Y=\mathbf{y})$."

In the case of a pmf, whats the difference between $p(X)$ and $p(X=x)$?
And in the case of a pmf and pdf, is it valid to write it as $p(X)$? This is whats confusing me, because I assumed we write it as $p(x)$, not $p(X)$.

Comment: Please take special care to distinguish capital and lower case letters.  That will resolve some of your questions.  It is unfortunate that these authors heavily abuse notation, anyway.  Indeed, from this excerpt it isn't at all evident what kind of mathematical object something like "$p(X)$" might be: a probability? A probability *function*? A probability function applied to a random variable?  A density?  Etc., etc. In such cases about all you can do is work out the intended meaning from each use, taking the "explanation" as a set of hints.